# mapView:didSelectAnnotationView gets fired only once

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a MKMapView, I display one MKAnnotaionView on top of it. My problem is when I click on the AnnotationView the first time, `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView` gets called, but if I click on it again nothing happens. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView
    {
        indexPathTag=aView.tag;
        [mapView deselectAnnotation:aView.annotation animated:YES];

    }
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView
    {
    }
```

When didSelectAnnotationView fires, it actually tags the annotation as selected somehow. Then when you click it again, the delegate function doesn't fire because it is 'already selected'. You have to manually deselect the annotation by calling the following function once you're done doing what you want. So you have to Add [mapView deselectAnnotation:aView.annotation animated:YES]; in didSelectAnnotationView delegate method.

Comment: but if you want to tap on an empty area in the mapview, this will not work.